# Carousel slider won't slide as expected

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently attempting to create a carousel in html and js. My code appears to be correct but for some reason the pictures do not slide. Am I missing something? What could I add?
Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="carousel-container">
    <div class="carousel-slide">
        <img src="./img/artpic3.jpg" id="lastClone" alt="">
        <img src="./img/artpic1.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="./img/artpic2.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="./img/artpic3.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="./img/artpic1.jpg" id="firstClone" alt="">
    </div>
</div>


<button id="prevBtn">Prev</button>
<button id="nextBtn">Next</button>

<script src="app.js"></script>
```

JavaScript:

```
const carouselSlide = document.querySelector('.carousel-slide');
const carouselImages = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel-slide img');


const prevBtn = document.querySelector('#prevBtn');
const nextBtn = document.querySelector('#nextBtn');


let counter = 1;
const size = carouselImages[0].clientWidth;

carouselSlide.style.transform = 'tranlateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';


nextBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
carouselSlide.style.transition = "transform 0.6s ease-in-out";
counter++;
carouselSlide.style.transform = 'tranlateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';
});
prevBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
carouselSlide.style.transition = "transform 0.4s ease-in-out";
counter--;
carouselSlide.style.transform = 'tranlateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';
});
```

CSS:

```
.carousel-container { 
    width: 70%; margin: auto; border: 5px solid white; overflow: hidden;
}
.carousel-slide {
    display: flex; width: 100%; height: 500px;
}
```

Comment: Please post relevant code snippets of your CSS too.

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: @AndrewL64 I didn't think it was required but here is the relevant css code: .carousel-container {     width: 70%;     margin: auto;     border: 5px solid white;     overflow: hidden; }  .carousel-slide {     display: flex;     width: 100%;     height: 500px; }

Comment: @isherwood. No there aren't any console errors. I even tried console.log(counter) and the the counter was working. For some reason the transition does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your carousel.

1. You wrote `translateX` as `tranlateX`.
2. `carouselImages[0].clientWidth` is initially `0` and since you have assigned it to a constant variable, it remains `0` and thus, keeps multiplying the `counter` with `0` every time the prev/next buttons are clicked.

Just change `(-size * counter)` to `(-carouselImages[0].clientWidth * counter)` and your carousel should work fine.

---

Check and run the following **Code Snippet** for a practical example of the carousel with the above changes:

```js
const carouselSlide = document.querySelector('.carousel-slide');
const carouselImages = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel-slide img');


const prevBtn = document.querySelector('#prevBtn');
const nextBtn = document.querySelector('#nextBtn');


let counter = 1;

carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-carouselImages[0].clientWidth * counter) + 'px)';


nextBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
carouselSlide.style.transition = "transform 0.6s ease-in-out";
counter++;
carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-carouselImages[0].clientWidth * counter) + 'px)';
});
prevBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
carouselSlide.style.transition = "transform 0.4s ease-in-out";
counter--;
carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-carouselImages[0].clientWidth * counter) + 'px)';
});
```

```css
.carousel-container { width: 70%; margin: auto; border: 5px solid white; overflow: hidden; }
.carousel-slide { display: flex; width: 100%; height: 500px; }
```

```html
<div class="carousel-container">
    <div class="carousel-slide">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1420/550?random=1" id="lastClone" alt="">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1420/550?random=2" alt="">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1420/550?random=3" alt="">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1420/550?random=4" alt="">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1420/550?random=5" alt="">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1420/550?random=6" alt="">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1420/550?random=7" alt="">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/1420/550?random=1" alt="">
    </div>
</div>


<button id="prevBtn">Prev</button>
<button id="nextBtn">Next</button>
```

Comment: Works like a charm. I'll now have to live with the fact that I spent an hour looking over the code and didn't notice the "tranlate".